# What specific federal laws do you think Thoreau contended made him "an agent of injustice" toward the slaves?

Tags: meaning, history, quotes

if the unjustice is part of the necessary friction of the machine of government, let it go...perchance it will wear smooth-certainly the machine will wear out... if it is of such a nature that it requires you to be the agent of injustice to another then I say break the law. let your life be a counter friction to stop the machine.

Comment: Please tell us where you are having difficulty with it. It would also be helpful to tell us where you are quoting from.

Comment: Henry David Thoreau. I'm not sure how to write a hook for a paper with this as my quote to go off of.

Comment: @ColinFine It's Thoreau's *Civil Disobedience*, with some typos which don't affect the question.

Comment: And do the "..." ellipses represent stuff you've omitted, or were they in the original text?

Comment: Read the article about Thoreau in, I think, the Oct 19 issue of *The New Yorker*.  His writing wasn't really all that deep.

Comment: original text and I don't know how to write an introductory sentence, help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for writing advice.  Sorry emily...

Comment: @emily A man has confessed in open court to breaking an unjust law.  As a   juror do you vote guilty because the judicial rules require it or do you vote not guilty (and thus violate your oath as a juror) to avoid becoming an agent of injustice?  If the latter, what responsibility do you have if jurors start to vote their feelings instead of regarding the evidence?  [Can you take it from here?]

Answer (score 1):

He is saying that sometimes the workings of government will result in occasional injustice.  However, if a particular circumstance would require that *you* impart harm on another person, he's advising you break the law.

An example that comes to mind is when someone steps in to help someone in peril, and then is sued because of the outcome.  This out-of-control tort resulted in many people not helping others in trouble, fearing the outcome.  Several states have implemented 'Good Samaritan' laws as a result of this.  That would be an example of the machine "wearing smooth" as a result of friction.

Comment: I'm not positive I agree with every aspect of your interpretation, but it is a good answer nevertheless. +1. Don